# UITableView skipping every other cell when populating labels swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create several UITableViews programmatically in the same scroll view. I'm correctly loading the tables' data into each array, but for some reason the table is populating every other cell. I added a print statement in cellForRowAt: to make sure it wasn't skipping data somehow and it doesn't seem to.

Also, didSelectRowAt: isn't being called when I click on a row, but didHighlightRowAt: is called correctly. And using that the table cells seem to load properly, it's just skipping every other cell when populating them.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cellIdentifier = ""

    switch tableView {
    case tableView1:
        cellIdentifier = "AddOnTableViewCell1"
    case tableView2:
        cellIdentifier = "AddOnTableViewCell2"
    case tableView3:
        cellIdentifier = "AddOnTableViewCell3"
    case tableView4:
        cellIdentifier = "AddOnTableViewCell4"
    default:
        print("Too many tables")
    }


    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? AddOnTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("Dequed cell error")
    }

    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: cell.frame.minY + 10, width: view.frame.width - 30, height: 30))
    titleLabel.textColor = .black
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .left

    switch tableView {
    case tableView1:
        titleLabel.text = addOnContents1[indexPath.row]
        print("\(indexPath.row), \(addOnContents1[indexPath.row])")
    case tableView2:
        titleLabel.text = addOnContents2[indexPath.row]
        print("\(indexPath.row), \(addOnContents2[indexPath.row])")
    case tableView3:
        titleLabel.text = addOnContents3[indexPath.row]
        print("\(indexPath.row), \(addOnContents3[indexPath.row])")
    case tableView4:
        titleLabel.text = addOnContents4[indexPath.row]
        print("\(indexPath.row), \(addOnContents4[indexPath.row])")
    default:
        print("Too many tables")
    }

    cell.addSubview(titleLabel)




    return cell
}
```

The print statements above show that the data added correctly corresponds to the indexRow.path, i.e. 0 is item00, 1 is item01, 2 is item02, 3 is item03, ...

Then here are the other two methods mentioned.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch tableView {
    case tableView1:
        print(addOnContents1[indexPath.row])
    case tableView2:
        print(addOnContents2[indexPath.row])
    case tableView3:
        print(addOnContents3[indexPath.row])
    case tableView4:
        print(addOnContents4[indexPath.row])
    default:
        print("Too many tables")
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Pressed")
    switch tableView {
    case tableView1:
        print(indexPath.row)
    case tableView2:
        print(indexPath.row)
    case tableView3:
        print(indexPath.row)
    case tableView4:
        print(indexPath.row)
    default:
        print("Too many tables")
    }

}
```

Finally, here's my code for setting up the tableViews

```
func loadAddOnViews() {
    var count = 1
    for item in addOns {
        var contentSize: CGFloat = 0
        switch count {
        case 1:
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: yCoordinateForNewContent, width: scrollView.frame.width - 32, height: 50))
            label.text = addOns[0].title
            yCoordinateForNewContent += 50
            scrollView.addSubview(label)
            contentSize = CGFloat(addOnContents1.count)
            print("content size: \(contentSize)")
            contentSize = contentSize * cellSize
            tableView1 = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: yCoordinateForNewContent, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: contentSize))
            scrollView.addSubview(tableView1)
            tableView1.delegate = self
            tableView1.dataSource = self
            self.tableView1.register(AddOnTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AddOnTableViewCell1")
            yCoordinateForNewContent += contentSize + 20
            tableView1.reloadData()

        case 2:
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: yCoordinateForNewContent, width: scrollView.frame.width - 32, height: 50))
            label.text = addOns[1].title
            yCoordinateForNewContent += 50
            scrollView.addSubview(label)
            contentSize = CGFloat(addOnContents2.count)
            print("content size: \(contentSize)")
            contentSize = contentSize * cellSize
            tableView2 = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: yCoordinateForNewContent, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: contentSize))
            scrollView.addSubview(tableView2)
            tableView2.delegate = self
            tableView2.dataSource = self
            self.tableView2.register(AddOnTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AddOnTableViewCell2")
            yCoordinateForNewContent += contentSize + 20
            tableView2.reloadData()
        case 3:
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: yCoordinateForNewContent, width: scrollView.frame.width - 32, height: 50))
            label.text = addOns[2].title
            yCoordinateForNewContent += 50
            scrollView.addSubview(label)
            contentSize = CGFloat(addOnContents3.count)
            print("content size: \(contentSize)")
            contentSize = contentSize * cellSize
            tableView3 = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: yCoordinateForNewContent, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: contentSize))
            scrollView.addSubview(tableView3)
            tableView3.delegate = self
            tableView3.dataSource = self
            self.tableView3.register(AddOnTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AddOnTableViewCell3")
            yCoordinateForNewContent += contentSize + 20
            tableView3.reloadData()
        case 4:
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: yCoordinateForNewContent, width: scrollView.frame.width - 32, height: 50))
            label.text = addOns[3].title
            yCoordinateForNewContent += 50
            scrollView.addSubview(label)
            contentSize = CGFloat(addOnContents4.count)
            print("content size: \(contentSize)")
            contentSize = contentSize * cellSize
            tableView4 = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: yCoordinateForNewContent, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: contentSize))
            scrollView.addSubview(tableView4)
            tableView4.delegate = self
            tableView4.dataSource = self
            self.tableView4.register(AddOnTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AddOnTableViewCell4")
            yCoordinateForNewContent += contentSize + 20
            tableView4.reloadData()
        default:
            print("too many tables")
        }
        count += 1
    }
}
```

And here's the screen with example data:
[SimulatorScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkzCg.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: May I ask what the row height is for the table views?

Comment: The row height is 40. I tried increasing it to 90 to see if anything changed but it didn't.

Comment: And have you used the view debugger to check the cells are there?

Comment: Yeah they appear to all be there

Comment: Do you really want all the switch statements without `break`? Share the code so that we can debug and help.

Comment: I added breaks and it didn't seem to help. The class is about 700 lines of code so I don't want to share it all

Comment: How do you fill addOnContents1 and other arrays like this?

Comment: What kind of design are you ultimately trying to accomplish?  Would a grouped tableview or collection view be better suit your needs?  Also refactoring your data model into a simple, custom struct will help simplify your logic.

Comment: first of all, your cell has too many labels. Because you are adding new labels to a reusable cell, which will already have a label. So declare your titleLabel in the AddOnTableViewCell class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Naresh for bringing my attention to this. I had declared the label in the AddOnTableViewCell class, but I was creating a label in the cellForRowAt: method, which I was adding as a subview to the cell. I simplified the tables to a single table with an array of arrays to hold the data. I made the following change to my AddOnTableViewCell class:

```
class AddOnTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var titleLabel: UILabel!

init(frame: CGRect, title:String) {
    super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "AddOnTableViewCell")
    titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 16 , y: self.frame.minY + 10, width: self.frame.width - 32, height: 40))
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    titleLabel.text = title
    addSubview(titleLabel)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}}
```

and I simplified my cellForRowAt: method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let title = tableContents[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    let cell = AddOnTableViewCell(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: cellSize), title: title)


    return cell
}
```

Thanks!